# ComboBox word not recognized when using it in VBA, in a form on MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in Microsoft Access.

It has 2 fields related to this issue.

- `Sending_Expense_Category`:

  This field is a combo box pulling a list of items from another table through wizard lookup. 2 categories in the drop-down are `Contractors` and `Salaries` & `Benefits`.
- `Account`:

  This is also a field pulling from another table. It has a list containing, but not limited to, the following values: `A500005`, `A502300`).

I am trying to do a simple if statement.

This code doesn't give me an error, but it also doesn't update the account area with the value. If I delete the link from the table to `Sending_Expense_Category` (unbound table) and type in contractors it works.

I have searched all over the web but to no avail. I think I am googling the wrong question (novice).

```
Private Sub Sending_Expense_Category_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Sending_Expense_Category = "Contractors" Then
        Me.Account = "A500005"
    End If
End Sub
```

The expected result should be when contractors are selected out of `Sending_Expense_Category`, then the account field should auto-populate with the number `A500005`.

No error messages are received.

Comment: Which column is bound to the combo box control `Sending_Expense_Category`? So, will there really be the value `Contractors` being stored in its `Value` property, or any number/abbreviation?

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- inspect the combo boxes values while stepping through the code.

Comment: @UnhandledException the combo box control is linked to the 'PacingCategories' table. From there it is linked to a hidden column ID and a showing column called Expense_Categories which include "Contractors" and Salaries and Benefits. How would I tell if its a number its referring too? Thanks

Comment: @Andre - I after the event was triggered, no code was triggered. the Locals table was empty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the Sending_Expense_Category table have an ID column (or other primary key) ? And is the combo box bound to that column instead of the text column? Place a breakpoint at the line 
 `If Me.Sending_Expense_Category = "Contractors" Then`

and check what the value of Sending_Expense_Category is.

Also, it is a good idea to name your controls (textboxes, comboboxes) something other than the name of the field it is bound to. Access can get confused about which entity you are referring to if they have the same names.

Comment: Sending _Expense_Category table does have an ID column as the primary key. Combo box could be tied to that column instead (not sure) The ID column is on but hidden. 

The code never triggers, so the Locals window doesn't have anything to show for the code. 

Thanks for the type. I will start naming them!

Comment: In the properties window, you can change the bound column to be 2 (assuming the row source for the combo box is something like "SELECT ID, Category FROM tbl") so that the "value" of the combo box will be the category as text and not the ID number.

Comment: I tried bound column 1, 2, and 3. When doing this I also updated the format to short text (was number). When selecting "contractors" from the drop down nothing happens with the code. 

my row source is "SELECT [PacingCategories].[ID], [PacingCategories].[Expense_Category], [PacingCategories].[Account] FROM PacingCategories ORDER BY [ID]; "

Any other ideas? I really appreciate the help

Comment: In the property window for the combo box, does the After Update event contain "Event Procedure" ? If not, select it from the list and double click it, it should take you to the code you have already written for it. Sometimes the events get disconnected from the object they should be attached to.

Answer (score -1):

You can do what you need very easily without coding.

The second combo box has to read his data from a query in which you filter by the category selected on the first combo box.